# It takes ages to type into the styled M-UI TextFields when I call onChange collecting input field data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, babeljs

So my problem is that when I type into the textfields it takes like 2 seconds to write a character and to log it out into the console, I tried to use React.memo and useCallback but it fails :/
Here is my code:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
 const handleDataChange = (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    setUserData({
      [name]: value
    })
  }
  console.log(userData);
  <div className="user__infoRow">
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="First Name" name="fname" onChange={handleDataChange} />
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="Last Name" name="lname" onChange={handleDataChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="user__infoRow">
            <TextField variant="filled" type="email" label="email" name="email" onChange={handleDataChange} />
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="Phone number" name="phone" onChange={handleDataChange} />
          </div>
```

P.S it's my first post , sorry if I did it wrong

Comment: Code appears fine (*though you shouldn't log in the body of a functional component*) and works here in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/it-takes-ages-to-type-into-the-styled-m-ui-textfields-when-i-call-onchange-colle-fk8vv) after fixing your state update function. What else is this component doing? Can you reproduce your issue into a *running* codesandbox?

Comment: Ok so I found a way that I could achieve the same result, thanks for paying attention to my question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a way that I could achieve the same result.
I wrapped the inputs in a form and set It to fire the function onSubmit and to target the fields I  just used e.target.elements.name.value
Here is the code :

```js
 const handleDataChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUserData({
      ["fName"] : e.target.elements.fname.value,
      ["lName"] : e.target.elements.lname.value,
      ["email"] : e.target.elements.email.value,
      ["phone"] : e.target.elements.phone.value,
    })
  }
  
  <form className="user__info" onSubmit={handleDataChange}>
 <div className="user__infoRow">
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="First Name" name="fname" />
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="Last Name" name="lname" />
          </div>
          <div className="user__infoRow">
            <TextField variant="filled" type="email" label="email" name="email" />
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="Phone number" name="phone" />
          </div>
</form>
```